# How to organize such a UI in android?

Tags: android

My current UI consists of 3 activity/dialog
1. activity A --- a listview and a "add" button, and activity B is shown when clicking the button.
2. activity B --- see http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/9872/9120120905101922.png for its layout. And when selecting "select", dialog C is shown.
3. dialog C --- a spinner or listview for user to select an item.

I want to make the process more compact and professional, as the whole process contains presentation of 3 activity/dialog, (in fact there's 4 activity/dialog because there's an activity M before activity A!)

What I choose to do now is to change activity B to a dialog, and change dialog C to a popup.But as I mentioned before, after the changes, there are still 4 activity/dialogs totally , so these changes would not make much sense.

What should I do? Is it possible to replace activity B and dialog C with a single dialog D?

Comment: To make it clear --- My aim is to make the user interaction process more compact (less steps). Going through 4 steps/activities is surely too complicated. 2 activities plus a popup/dialog seems better for me, can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you can't show the spinner/listview from activity C under the OK/Cancel buttons in Activity B? Best I can tell there's only one element on Activity C, so it'll be wasting a lot of space (and B has plenty to spare).

Regardless, I wouldn't worry too much about the complexity of having four Activities in your program and stressing over optimising it down to three. Pretty much any device should be able to handle that many Activities with ease.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, making C under B is a good option. But is that UI convenient for user? How could I make such effect --- I mean selecting one radiobox will make the spinner/listview show? How could I do this in a user-friendly way(common way)?